# Adding cross project service account in GCP cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts, google-iam

We have added a `IAM service account` from `Project A` to `project B` in GCP with `Cloud function Admin permissions`

We are now trying to create a cloud function in `project B`  using the same `service account` .

But the `service account` is not listed in the drop down menu during creation of `Cloud functions`. Only the `service accounts` which are locally created are visible in the drop down menu.

[image]

Any suggestion to use cross `service accounts` in `cloud functions` ?

Comment: Have you already checked [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#individual) documentation? I have not set up this type of cross-project service accounts, but it seems to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Service Accounts from external projects as a runtime SA for a Cloud Function, this is why you don't see the service account in the dropdown menu.

When you grant permissions to the Service Account from `Project A` in `Project B` you only do that, grant permissions. Keep in mind that the SA continues being part of `project A` and not `project B`.

This works in the same way as [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth#setting_up_the_service_account):

> The service account must belong to the same project as the one in which the Cloud Scheduler jobs are created.

What the [steps here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#attaching-different-project) suggest to make this possible is to impersonate a the Service Account from `project A` using a service account of `project B` but you will notice that actually you attach an account from the same project were the function is.

If you need to access to resources in `project A` from `project B` then use in your function a SA from the same project and add the needed permissions for that SA in `project A` or use the impersonation approach if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm flummoxed :-(

I tried this using `gcloud` and am unable to get it work.

I tried granting the Cloud Functions project's Compute Engine service account `roles/serviceAccountUser` on the desired (remote) Service Account but I continue to get:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) PERMISSION_DENIED:
Permission 'iam.serviceaccounts.actAs' denied on service account
${ACCOUNT}@${OTHER-PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Perhaps the remote account need Cloud Functions deploy permissions too?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it possible to use service account across projects to deploy Cloud Function.

Please follow below mentioned link to grant the necessary permissions.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#gcloud_2

---

If the service account and the function are in different projects, from the project where the service account is located:

Configure the service account to work across projects.
Grant the Service Account Token Creator role (roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator) to both of these Google-managed service accounts:

App Engine default service account (PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com)
Cloud Functions Service Agent (service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com)
These Google accounts manage cross-project access for your service account.

Grant the service account access to the resource. The method for doing this depends on the resource type.

Connect the service account with your function. You can do this either at deployment time or by updating a previously deployed function.

---

Using the above guidance we are still not able to view the new SA across the projects but able to deploy the same via CLI.

### Sample CLI is as below

### gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME 
--trigger-topic TOPIC_NAME --region REGION_NAME --runtime RUNTIME --entry-point ENTRY_POINT --service-account SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL

Please note: While deploying the CF using CLI, you need to be in working directory where main.py and other files are located.

Comment: This answer is not related to the question. The OP wants to use a cross-project SA at runtime and not to deploy a function using a cross-project SA as you state in the beggining. Anyway I've tested these steps and actually those don't work. Please test your steps or at least mention you've not tested them if that's the case